# Tensorflow : how to add summary into dynamic_rnn cell

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently trying to build an NN whitch involves a custom RNN cell.
I would like to see the evolution of a weight matrix into the cell's **call**. Note that I am using a dynamic _rnn. 
So, to do that I add the line

```
tf.summary.histogram("H", self.H);
```

I get the folowing errror :

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 
>   The node 'Merge/MergeSummary' has inputs from different frames. The
>   input 'Logits/RNN/rnn/while/CellRNN/while/H' is in frame
>   'Logits/RNN/rnn/while/CellRNN/while/Logits/RNN/rnn/while/CellRNN
>   /while/'.
>   The input 'Accuracy/class_accuracy/class_accurancy' is in frame ' '.

Comment: Up, does someone is in the same case ?